# How to close viber main window

Tags: c#, viber

I'm developing a tiny launcher. Its main idea is to fix the lack of functionality in Viber for Windows.
I want it to make start Viber minimized to tray only.
Normally, when Viber is starting, it appears a Viber main window on desktop and an icon - in system tray. All the time I should close this obsolete window manually.
So, I have written a few lines of code, but I found that it still couldn't close the window:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class ViberStrt {
    static void Main() {

        Process newProc = Process.Start("c:\\Users\\Dmytro\\AppData\\Local\\Viber\\Viber.exe");
        Console.WriteLine("New process has started");
        //newProc.CloseMainWindow();
        newProc.WaitForExit();
        newProc.Close();
        newProc.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Process has finished");
        //newProc.Kill();
    }
}
```

But whatever I tried (Close, Dispose) - it does not work.
Method Kill does not fit, because it kills all. But the only thing I need is to close Viber main window and leave the process in the System Tray.

There is also another way: to start Viber minimized at once:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class LaunchViber
{
    void OpenWithStartInfo()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("c:\\Users\\Dmytro\\AppData\\Local\\Viber\\Viber.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;        
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        //Process newProc = Process.Start("c:\\Users\\Dmytro\\AppData\\Local\\Viber\\Viber.exe");
        LaunchViber newProc = new LaunchViber();
        newProc.OpenWithStartInfo();
    }
}
```

In such a case, we receive a minimized window on the TaskPane and an icon in the SystemTray. But in this case I have absolutely no idea how to get rid of the icon (how to close minimized window) on the TaskPane.

I shall appreciate any help/ ideas in finding a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pinvoke, you can try getting the handle for the actual window if you know what the window caption will be.

First, import these functions:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

And you may want to declare the `WM_CLOSE` constant:

```
const UInt32 WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
```

Then the code to close the window (but keep the process running the in background):

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Users\Dmytro\AppData\Local\Viber\Viber.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
var newProc = Process.Start(startInfo);

var name = "Viber +381112223344";
var windowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, name);

while (windowPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    windowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, name);
}

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

SendMessage(windowPtr, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Thank you for the brief response.

Comment: I've tried to use your code, but nothing has changed: Viber starts and then its main window still remains opened.

Comment: @Dmytro okay, without seeing what you have done I would suggest first checking the value of `windowPtr` to make sure it found the window (you might have supplied the wrong caption or something similar). If you update your question with your full attempt I will have a closer look at it

Comment: @Dmytro Feel free to comment here if you need further help!

Comment: Yes, @Bassie, I am afraid, that I am using wrong caption, but I don't know how to check it. I tried to insert, the code, which I have here, but I am receiving warning, that my message is too large.

Comment: @Dmytro You can edit your original question and include the code there

Comment: Wow, It looks, like I've found out the problem.

Comment: Everything is ok, but Viber starts slower, than my code runs. I've substantially modified it, added some time to wait and now it seems like it works good (as I want). I've managed to hide the window and than - to close it. If you know better solution (without waiting) - it would appreciate it a lot. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Dmytro Please see my updated answer. Logically, I don't see why the Sleep should be needed (as the while loop should never exit until the window handle is available) - but I was also seeing the issue that you mentioned. With the above method the program should at leas wait until the window is available before waiting for 100 ms - let me know if that works!

Comment: @Dmytro Also, I meant update YOUR question, not my answer!

Comment: I don't know, if you can help further, but I have some new ideas to update this code.:) 1. Is it possible to use a relative path instead of c:\\Users\\Dmytro\\? 2. Is it possible to catch any Viber window (not only with my phone number). So, the idea is to make this launcher universal and make it work not only in my notebook.

Comment: @Dmytro That's great that it is working! You should mark this as the answer and maybe create a new question for the other stuff (as they are different problems)

Comment: @Dmytro (1) Off the top of my head, I'm not sure if you can set a relative path, but maybe google how to find installed applications on a computer, and (2) There should be a way to enumerate all windows, then just find one where the caption contains `viber`

Comment: Ok, @Bassie, thank you again for your help. I'll do as you suggest.